# Finding similar substrings in two separate strings

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one with a column containing strings representing a stock exchange (e.g. 'BrsaItaliana') and the other with a different string for same stock exchange (e.g. 'Italian Stock Exchange'). How can I check if substring of former is contained in latter (e.g. 'Italian' is contained in both)? I have tried the below query but I realize this is incorrect as the operation treats eqs.primary_exchange as the "substring" whereas I'd like to locate a common substring using a substring of eqs.primary_exchange.

```
CREATE TABLE `yahoo_exchange_suffix`
(`exchange`        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Long Name of Stock Exchange' ,
 `country`         VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Long name of country where exchange is located' ,
 `exchange_suffix` VARCHAR(10) COMMENT 'The code appended to ticker to denote a securities exchange.' ,
) COMMENT='Table provides list of used suffixes for non-US equity exchanges in order to properly interact with Yahoo Finance';

CREATE TABLE `equity_symbols`
(`ISIN`                   CHAR(12) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique 12 character alphanumeric identifier for any security' ,
 `company_name`           VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Long company name attributed to security' ,
 `symbol`                 VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL COMMENT 'the string that identifies the security on local exchange' ,
 `bbg_symbol`             VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The string that identifies the security in bloomberg terminal' ,
 `company_description`    VARCHAR(1000) COMMENT 'Description of the company associated with ISIN' ,
 `domicile`               VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Location of headquarters' ,
 `category`               VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of security issued (e.g. COMMON STOCK, DEPOSITORY RECEIPT, etc)' ,
 `security_currency`      CHAR(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Currency denomination of security' ,
 `local_currency`         CHAR(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Currency issuer reports financials' ,
 `gics_sector_name`       VARCHAR(100) COMMENT 'String identifying the sector membership of security' ,
 `gics_industry_grp_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'String identifying the industry group of a security' ,
 `gics_industry_name`     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'String identifying a security\'s membership in an industry' ,
 `gics_sub_industry_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'String identifying the sub-industry membership of a security ' ,
 `gics_sector`            TINYINT COMMENT 'Code for securitys GICS sector' ,
 `gics_industry_grp`      SMALLINT COMMENT 'Code for GICS Industry Group' ,
 `gics_industry`          INT COMMENT 'Code for GICS industry' ,
 `gics_sub_industry`      INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Code for GICS Sub-Industry' ,
 `primary_exchange`       VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Exchange where security trades' ,
 `primary_mic`            CHAR(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Market Identification Code (MIC) for primary exchange' ,

 PRIMARY KEY (`ISIN`) COMMENT 'Unique 12 character alphanumeric code to identify securities.')
 COMMENT='This table will hold list of securities of interest to us whether for analytics, risk, research, etc. May ';


SELECT DISTINCT(eqs.primary_exchange) AS primary_exch,  
      y.exchange AS exch  
FROM equity_symbols eqs  
INNER JOIN yahoo_exchange_suffix y  
ON y.exchange LIKE CONCAT('%',eqs.primary_exchange,'%')
```

[Details of tables with expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdabq.jpg)

Thanks for you time and I look forward to comments/advice.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do this. Finding common substrings is a huge combinatorial explosion. And almost everything will match. E.g. `America` and `Italiana` both have the common substring `a`.

Comment: I agree searching for any substring of string1 being contained in string2, but with updated tables key is that primary_exchange and exchange contain a substring corresponding to a country. Would it make sense to have a separate table with list of countries and then JOIN each table with country table and then JOIN the result?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. It will still be slow because an index can't be used to optimize patterns that begin with `%`.

Comment: `FROM countries JOIN table1 ON table1.col LIKE CONCAT('%', countries.country, '%') JOIN table2 ON table2.col LIKE CONCAT('%', countries.country, '%')`

Comment: `FROM countries JOIN table1 ON INSTR(countries.country, table1.col) > 0 JOIN table2 ON INSTR(countries.country, table2.col) > 0`  
@Barmar Would this improve speed?

Comment: It will probably be the same. Either way, it can't use an index.

Comment: The index is a B-tree, it can only optimize matches that start at the beginning of the column. Once you search for a substring match, you lose all optimization possibilities.

Comment: This is why searching large text is done using full-text indexes.